# TSql xml query is concatenating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I query an xml column in a temp variable, the results are being concatenated if an xml element has multiple values.  Below is an excerpt from the xml column-

```
 <metadata>
   <dataType>Date</dataType>
    <tags>
      <tag>SPA</tag>
      <tag>Timed Release</tag>
    </tags>
 </metadata>
```

Notice the two tag elements.  I need one row for each tag element.  Here is my query-

```
 SELECT id,
    dataType = [Type].value('(/metadata/tags)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
 FROM
@tmpProperty
```

that produces the below

```
 id   | dataType
 -----+-------------------
 6357 | SPATimed Release
```

if I change the query to

```
 SELECT id,
dataType = [Type].value('(/metadata/tags/tag)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM
@tmpProperty
```

I get

```
 id   | dataType
 -----+-----------
 6357 | SPA
```

Both results are wrong.  One concatenates into a single row instead of 2 rows, and the other just returns one value.  I am using sql server 2012.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188282.aspx) first to get multiple rows, then you can use [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract the data:

```
DECLARE @tmpProperty TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, [Type] XML);
INSERT @tmpProperty([Type])
VALUES ('<metadata>
   <dataType>Date</dataType>
    <tags>
      <tag>SPA</tag>
      <tag>Timed Release</tag>
    </tags>
 </metadata>');

 SELECT id,
        dataType = Tags.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
 FROM   @tmpProperty AS t
        CROSS APPLY t.[Type].nodes('/metadata/tags/tag') AS n (Tags);
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!